# Error: transaction check vs depsolve when upgrading to fedora 27

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, installation, fedora, fedora-27

**Running transaction check
Error: transaction check vs depsolve:
(php-composer(google/recaptcha) >= 1.1 with php-composer(google/recaptcha) < 2) is needed by phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-1.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(phpmyadmin/motranslator) >= 4.0 with php-composer(phpmyadmin/motranslator) < 5) is needed by phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-1.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(phpmyadmin/shapefile) >= 2.0 with php-composer(phpmyadmin/shapefile) < 3) is needed by phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-1.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(phpmyadmin/sql-parser) >= 4.2.3 with php-composer(phpmyadmin/sql-parser) < 5) is needed by phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-1.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(phpseclib/phpseclib) >= 2.0.9 with php-composer(phpseclib/phpseclib) < 3) is needed by phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-1.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(tecnickcom/tcpdf) >= 6.2 with php-composer(tecnickcom/tcpdf) < 7) is needed by phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-1.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(composer/ca-bundle) >= 1.0 with php-composer(composer/ca-bundle) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(composer/semver) >= 1.0 with php-composer(composer/semver) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(composer/spdx-licenses) >= 1.2 with php-composer(composer/spdx-licenses) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(psr/log) >= 1.0 with php-composer(psr/log) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(seld/cli-prompt) >= 1.0 with php-composer(seld/cli-prompt) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(seld/jsonlint) >= 1.4 with php-composer(seld/jsonlint) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
(php-composer(seld/phar-utils) >= 1.0 with php-composer(seld/phar-utils) < 2) is needed by composer-1.6.3-4.fc27.noarch
To diagnose the problem, try running: 'rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest'.
You probably have corrupted RPMDB, running 'rpm --rebuilddb' might fix the issue.
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.**

> after the download is completed and running transactions it gived me an error

Comment: What was the output when you ran `rpm --rebuilddb`?

Comment: it gave me no output @IsaacBennetch

Comment: I don't know rpm very well, so that could be the intended result. It sounds like the next thing to do is to run `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` and see what that says - or just try the installation again; hopefully the --rebuilddb worked to repair the damage.

Comment: it gave me an error and when solve it the error is still exists

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Solution:
DNF removed all php and php-* stuff

I'll have to reinstall after upgrade.